# Declarative Services Strategy Pattern

Tags: osgi, strategy-pattern, declarative-services

I'm new at OSGI and Declarative Services, and I'm trying to implement a strategy, but I'm having trouble to get components Satisfied and/or Active

[image: Implementation Diagram]

My BillConfig has the useMocks(), when it's true the Repo that should be returned by the factory is the BillRepositoryInMemory, otherwise should be the BillRepositoryREST. How can I have access to an abstraction of this repos in my BillDAO?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your setup with a Factory does not look optimal for OSGi usage.
Instead I propose to create the repository impls as DS components with a required config policy.

This way you can activate the repo impl component you want by supplying it with a config.

In BillDAO you can then use:

```
@Reference
BillRepository repo;
```

This approach completely avoids the Factory pattern and makes your components much more loosely coupled.